# Distribution of test scores calculate cutoff given mean and standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution

A normal distribution of test scores has a mean of 38 and a standard deviation of 6. Everyone scoring at or above the 80th percentile gets placed in an advanced class. What is the cutoff score to get into the class?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE! We don't like to do your homework for you :), so could you please update your question with your thoughts/attempts to do the problem and we will be happy to guide you further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started: You need to find $a$ such that $P(X\leq a)=0.8$, where $X$ follows a normal distribution with a mean of 38 and standard deviation of 6. Now you need to standardize it. Remember that if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ then $\dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.